# weblogic + eclipselink + 2 different thread = lazyloading don`t work

Tags: caching, weblogic, lazy-loading, eclipselink

I have two threads one of them write text field to the database, another try to read this field but it can`t.

field has following anatation:

```
@Lob
    @Column(name = "response_soap")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public String getResponseSoap() {
        return responseSoap;
    }
```

Both thread it's part of the web application. Both running on the same weblogic server.
All transaction is commited. There is field in the database.
Every time I'm creating new Entity manager.

Comment: The problem was solved. I turned off shared cache. http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

Answer (score 1):

What error do you get?

Try using a refresh, em.refresh(object)

Are you serializing the object?  Since it is LAZY it will be null when you serialize it, unless you access before you serialize it.  Try making it EAGER.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that only 
Many-to_many and One-to-many are can be set to lazyload

One-to-one, Many-to-one and Basic are all Egar

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Lazy_Basics